# optimal query variant for msg senders table

Tags: mysql

I have table "s_msgs" and his structure is

```
id | from | to
------------------
1 | John | Robert
2 | John | Michael
3 | Robert | John 
4 | Michael | John
```

I need  obtain every message  sender-recipient couple, that is result must be

```
John | Robert 
John | Michael
```

I write query, but I think this is not optimal variant, all the more so expected that in table will be several milion rows, so can anyone tell more optimal query?

this is my query

```
          SELECT `from`,`to` FROM s_msgs WHERE id IN( 

             SELECT id FROM (
                 SELECT  MIN(id) AS id, 
                    CASE 
                        WHEN STRCMP(`to`,`from`) = -1 THEN CONCAT(`to`,`from`) 
                        ELSE CONCAT(`from`,`to`) 
                    END
                    AS conc
                FROM s_msgs

                GROUP BY conc

                ) AS t
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
SELECT DISTINCT `from`, `to`
FROM YOUR_TABLE
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT `to`,`from`
FROm YOUR_TABLE
```

**EDIT**

Got a new one, was the ID that saved me.

Have a look at this demo

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com//#!2/4c501/12/0)

```
SELECT *
FROM   MY_TABLE f 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1 
                    FROM MY_TABLE t 
                    WHERE f.`from` = t.`to` 
                    AND f.`to` = t.`from` 
                    AND f.id > t.id)
```

Comment: Thanks but this query returns every rows from table. needed every couple only 1 times. that is **Jhon - Robert** and **Robert- Jhon** is 1 couple and result must only: **Jhon - Robert**